# get value from a table if its checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of code where values are coming from php

```
<table class="table datatable-basic">
  <tr>
    <th>-<th>
    <th>title<th>
  </tr>
  //forloop
  <tr>
     <td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="uid[]" id="uid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><?php echo "$title" ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="go">GO</buton>
```

So in my jQuery, I want to alert the value of the check box which is `id`, when I click the button 'go' and when that check box is checked. How can I do this?

Comment: there will be multiple checkboxes...... which checkbox value you want to retrieve.

Comment: which ever is checked

Comment: they can be multiple?

Comment: i guess so so just concatenate with `,` commas

Answer (score 2):

You can use this selector `input.chk:checked` and the function `$.toArray` to get the selected elements as array and then execute the function `map` to get the values.

Finally, the function `join` will create an string with the values from the array separated by comma.

```js
$('#go').on('click', function() {
  var selectedValues = $('input.chk:checked').toArray().map(function(chk) {
    return $(chk).val();
  });

  console.log(selectedValues.join());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table datatable-basic">
  <tr>
    <th>title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="uid[]" id="uid" value="111"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="uid[]" id="uid" value="222"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="go">GO</buton>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with your setup - they all have an ID of "uid". IDs must be unique.

But since they have a class you can do this:

```
var selectedValues = [];
$('input.chk:checked').each(function() {
    selectedValues.push($(this).val());
});
```

The `selectedValues` array will contain the values of all of the selected checkboxes.

You could then join these together into a string separated by commas with `join`.

```
selectedValues.join(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate the output I have omitted the PHP part from HTML. You can try the following code:

```js
$('#go').click(function(){
  var val = '';
  $('.chk:checked').each(function(){
    val += ', ' + $(this).val();
  });
  
  alert(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table datatable-basic">
  <tr>
   <th>-<th>
   <th>title<th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="uid[]" id="uid" value="111"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="uid[]" id="uid" value="222"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="go">GO</buton>
```